# Manipulating Qt table cell spacing

Tags: css, qt, pyside

I'm looking for a way to squeeze all possible space out of `QTableWidget` cells. I've pasted some code to demonstrate the things I've tried below, and I've uploaded a screenshot produced on OSX 10.8.5, Qt 4.8.4, PySide 1.2.1. What I want is to be able to set `valueIWantToBeZero = 0` so that the cell is **exactly** the size of a single character, and I can pack as many columns into the available space as possible. If I set `valueIWantToBeZero = 0` in this example, the text disappears off the right side of the cell. There appears to be about 5 pixels of padding on the left side of each cell that I can't get rid of. There also appears to be 1 pixel at the top, and 2 at the bottom, but I don't care as much about vertical spacing.

How do I make the cells exactly the width of one character?

Thanks for any advice! :-)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class TableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      super(TableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
      font = QtGui.QFont("Courier",12,QtGui.QFont.Normal)
      font.setKerning(False)
      font.setLetterSpacing(QtGui.QFont.PercentageSpacing,0.0)
      font.setHintingPreference(QtGui.QFont.PreferNoHinting)
      font.setWordSpacing(0.0)
      self.setFont(font)

      self.setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section:horizontal {margin: 0px;  border: 0; padding 0px}")
      self.setStyleSheet("QTableView::item {padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0; background-color: orange; }")

      valueIWantToBeZero = 5
      hheader = self.horizontalHeader()
      hheader.setFont(font)
      hheader.setDefaultSectionSize(hheader.fontMetrics().width("A")+valueIWantToBeZero)
      vheader = self.verticalHeader()
      vheader.setDefaultSectionSize(vheader.fontMetrics().height())

      dim = 10
      self.setColumnCount(dim)
      self.setRowCount(dim)
      for r in range(dim):
         for c in range(dim):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(r))
            self.setItem(r,c,item)

def main():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = QtGui.QWidget()
   window.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
   tw = TableWidget(window)
   twLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
   twLayout.addWidget(tw)
   window.setLayout(twLayout)

   window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `QGraphicsScene` to draw the cells and grid lines exactly where I want them, so this is one possible answer to this question. That said, I still suspect there is a way to control all the margins of a `QTableWidget`, but perhaps not with this version of Qt?